# Alphanumeric subtrings sorting

Tags: java, sorting, alphanumeric, substring

I need to write a java code to covert `VBA7425IWC` to `ABV2457CIW`. I need help in that. If I sort the strings they sort by ASCII values and the numbers become one chunk and the alphabets another.

Answer (score 1):

This one uses regex.  You may have to adjust the pattern to include lower case letters:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SplitRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The search string
        String str = "VBA7425IWC";

        // The Regular expression (Finds {word} tokens)
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+|[0-9]+");

        // Match the string with the pattern
        Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);

        String result = "";
        // If results are found
        while (m.find()) {
            char[] chArray = m.group(0).toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(chArray);
            result += new String(chArray);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague in its requirements.  Are you attempting to sort each individual substring of characters and numbers?

In that case, you need to determine the ranges of each substring, denoted by a shift from characters to numbers.

```
start = 0
current = 0
for current = 0 to string.length-1:
    if ASCII of current is letter AND ASCII of next is number OR vice-versa:
        sort(string, start, current)
        start = current
```

You can find if a character is a letter or number by its ASCII value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample solution which I achive by dividing string intro numeric and alphabetic substrings stored in List and then sorted and reduce with java 8 stream API.

```
    String s = "VBA7425IWC";
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < s.length() - 1; k++) {
        subString.append(s.charAt(k));
        if ((Character.isDigit(s.charAt(k + 1))
                && Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(k))) ||
                (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(k))
                        && Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(k + 1)))) {
            mylist.add(subString.toString());
            subString.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    mylist.add(subString.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)).toString());
    System.out.println(mylist);
    String finalResult = mylist
            .stream()
            .map((myString) -> {
                char[] charArr = myString.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(charArr);
                return new String(charArr);

            })
            .reduce("", (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
```